# On an expansion of $(1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^n)^2$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, factoring

> **Question:** What is an easy or efficient way to see or prove that
>   $$
> 1+2a+3a^2+\cdots+na^{n-1}+(n+1)a^n+na^{n+1}+\cdots+3a^{2n-2}+2a^{2n-1}+a^{2n}\tag{1}
> $$
>   is equal to
>   $$
> (1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^n)^2\tag{2}
> $$
>   Maybe this is a particular case of a more general, well-known result?

**Context:** This is used with $a:=e^{it}$ to get an expression in terms of $\sin$ for the [Fejér kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel).

**Thoughts:** I thought about calculating the coefficient $c_k$ of $a^k$. But my method is not so obvious that we can get from $(1)$ to $(2)$ in the blink of an eye.

$\mathbf{k=0}$ : clearly $c_0=1$.

$\mathbf{1\leq k\leq n}$ : $c_k$ is the number of integer solutions of $x_1+x_2=k$ with $0\leq x_1,x_2\leq k$, which in turn is the number of ways we can choose a bar $|$ in
$$
\underbrace{|\star|\star|\cdots|\star|}_{k\text{ stars}}
$$
So $c_k=k+1$.

$\mathbf{k=n+i\quad(1\leq i\leq n)}$ : $c_k$ is the number of integer solutions to $x_1+x_k=n+i$ with $0\leq x_1,x_2\leq n$, which in turn is the number of ways we can choose a bar $|$ in
$$
\underbrace{|\star|\star|\cdots|\star|}_{n+i\text{ stars}}
$$
different from the $i$-th one from each side. So $c_k=(n+i)+1-2i=n-i+1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Don't forget, the square eventually stops, and so you get a diamond shape at the end)

[image]

Comment: Had you seen this in a "proofs without words" post or something? Pretty neat in any case! Thank you.

Comment: @NeedForHelp ***cough*** I'm the one who put it on the "proofs without words" post.

Answer (score 4):

Just multiply as,

$$1(1+a+a^2...+a^n)$$
$$+$$
$$a(1+a+a^2...+a^n)$$
$$+$$
$$a^2(1+a+a^2...+a^n)$$
$$+.....$$
$$a^n(1+a+a^2...+a^n)$$

This gives the sum of,

$$\begin{align}1+\ \ a+&\ \ a^2+\ \ a^3+\dots+\ \ a^n
\\\ \ a+&\ \ a^2+\ \ a^3+\dots+\ \ a^n+\ \ a^{n+1}
\\&\ \ a^2+\ \ a^3+\dots+\ \ a^n+\ \ a^{n+1}+\ \ a^{n+2}
\\&\quad\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a^3+\dots+\ \ a^n+\ \ a^{n+1}+\ \ a^{n+2}+\ \ a^{n+3}\\&\ \ \ \qquad\qquad\vdots\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\vdots
\\\hline1+2a+&3a^2+4a^3+\dots+(n+1)a^n+na^{n+1}+\dots+a^{2n}\end{align}$$

Comment: Does anyone know how can I line them up?

Comment: Does that look better?

Comment: Thank you so much @SimplyBeautifulArt

Answer (score 2):

Try to utilize a very well known formula: $$\left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2=\sum_i x_i^2+2\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j\,.$$ As you can see, I started from the end. But it does not matter for the proof.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use synthetic division twice after you you've rewritten the expression as 
$$\frac{(a^{n+1}-1)^2}{(a-1)^2}=\frac{a^{2n+2}-2a^{n+1}+1}{(a-1)^2}$$
$$\begin{array}{*{11}{r}}
&1&0&0&\dotsm&0&-2&0&0&\dots&0&0&1\\
&\downarrow&1&1&\dotsm&1&1&-1&-1&\dotsm&-1&-1&-1\\
\hline
\times1\quad&1&1&1&\dotsm&1&-1&-1&-1&\dotsm&-1&-1&0\\
&\downarrow&1&2&\dotsm&n&n+1&n&n-1&\dotsm&2&1\\
\hline
\times1\quad&1&2&3&\dotsm&n+1&n&n-1&n-2&\dotsm&1&0
\end{array}$$