# What is $(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

This may seem like a pretty basic question, but I am struggling to find a nice way of expressing $(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})^2$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}$. Plugging in some numbers yields a clear pattern,

$(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1})^2=1+2x+\cdots+nx^n+\cdots+2x^{2n-3}+x^{2n-2}.$

However, I can't seem to find a formal expression of this, or a proof. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: The expression inside the bracket is a geometric series.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129326/on-an-expansion-of-1aa2-cdotsan2

Comment: You can always do induction.  If $(1 + ... x^{n-1}) = \sum a_i x^i$ then $(1 + ... x^{n-1})^2 = \sum a_i x^i + 2\sum x^{n+i} + x^{2n} = \sum b_i x^i$ where $b_i = a_i$ if $i < n$ and $b_i = a_i + 2$ if $n \le i \le 2n-1$ and $b_{2n-1} = 1$.

Comment: compute straightforward the square of the polynomial $$(1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1})^2 = \sum_{i,j=0}^{n-1} x^ix^j $$ and now divide the sum into $i+1=0, i+j=1, i+j=2,\ldots$ and obtaining $$\sum_{i+j=0} x^ix^j + \sum_{i+j=1} x^ix^j + \sum_{i+j=2} x^ix^j + \ldots = 1 + (x^1x^0 + x^0x^1) + (x^2x^0+x^1x^2+x^0x^2) + \ldots = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \ldots + (n+1)x^n + \ldots $$

Answer (score 1):

So you can notice that there is a very nice elementary formula for partial sum of geometric progression, i.e.
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i = \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}
$$
It comes from the following argument
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i (1-x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^{i+1} = 1 - x^{n-1+1} = 1-x^n
$$
Therefore you can square to obtain
$$
\left( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i \right)^2 = \left( \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} \right)^2 = \frac{1+x^{2n} - 2x^n}{1+x^2-2x}
$$

Comment: This does not address the OP question, which is to prove that this is equal to $1+2x+\cdots+nx^n+\cdots+2x^{2n-3}+x^{2n-2}$

Comment: restate your problem next time, it wasn't clear at all!

Answer (score 1):

$$1+x+...+x^{n-1} = \frac{1\cdot(1-x^n)}{1-x},\quad x\neq 1$$

Then $$1+x+...+x^{n-1} = \bigg(\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\bigg)^2=\frac{1+x^{2n}-2x^n}{1+x^2-2x}$$

Comment: This does not address the OP question, which is to prove that this is equal to $1+2x+\cdots+nx^n+\cdots+2x^{2n-3}+x^{2n-2}$

Comment: @Sil "but I am struggling to find a nice way of expressing... " - this is a nice way of expressing his original expression.

Answer (score 0):

Its a sum of the GP with common ratio x. Thus apply the sum for a GP and then square it.